# echo message in each div or seperate css div in php

Tags: php, html, css, alert

I have the issue in PHP Codeigniter, Actually, I want to make a bootstrap or normal div wish alert box and want display error in each or separate div or toast. But when I apply the code and added in my PHP error code then all error shows in one div and when it empty or when not any error then the div show like below.

I want to make when the error comes it show in each or separate CSS div where for display error in CodeIgniter I am using this code.

```
 <div classs="myerror"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>

.myerror{
         background:url(https://manage.bigrock.in/images/ui-exclamation.png) no-repeat scroll 10px 10px #fbd0cd;
         border:2px solid #ce7873;
         padding:10px 10px 10px 34px;
         margin:15px 0 }
```

> I research on StackOverflow and google but I didn't get any answer about this, please do not mark this question as spam or duplicate and on hold. I believe this question will help everyone who just jumps on php now.

Comment: use separate error like <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>

it will print separate error for particular field. validation_errors(); will print all errors.

Comment: thank you for your comment @DevsiOdedra but what happen when I allowed for textbox as required in controller  `$this->form_validation->set_rules('mytextbox', 'textboxname', 'trim|required');` what I do for error ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 <div classs="myerror"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
```

use

```
<?php $validation_errors = validation_errors(); 
// now, you can use the variable to test if you have an error
// and display it only if you have the error
// NOTE: this presumes validation_errors() returns NOTHING if there is no error!
// if it returns something every time, then you have to do some other test!     
if(!empty($validation_errors){
?>
 <div class="myerror"><?php echo $validation_errors; ?></div>
<?php // you have to close the 'if'
} ?>
```

*(Note, this includes the corrected 'class' from 'classs' in the original question as commented....)*

Now, you have a variable that you can test for empty, use for other divs, error messages, whatever.....

(not enough code to rewrite it for you - though I trust this tip will help.

Comment: `classs`? New properties popping up all the time :)

Comment: :) - it was in the OP question - just copied/pasted..... - will correct!

Comment: it totally looks like my code but whatever when i use your code and paste it to my old place it show like this in this image.  `https://ibb.co/NTh6Dvn` please help

Comment: your image makes no sense (as I have no idea what you think it should do, nor what issue you feel it has....)  My code IS very much like your code - if all you  change is those lines....  You didn't really explain the issue or give enough code in your question to really help - but my answer does give you what I think is the next step - you will have a variable to work with and you can test for it being empty, etc. (so it will show/not...) - I'll mod my answer a bit to show what I mean here, but you need to clarify the issue if this isn't everything!